# Oracle SQL - Not null code is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to retrieve the monetary amount associated with project IDs, however I only want data where a project ID exists (not blank)

When I type my SQL code below...

```
SELECT project_id, monetary_amount, journal_line_date 
FROM PS_JRNL_LN 
where project_id is not null
  and journal_line_date BETWEEN to_date ('2020/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') 
                            AND TO_DATE ('2020/03/04','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

this query works however, I am still getting blank values in my result

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? Do you mean null, spaces, etc.?

Comment: As @TheImpaler is suggesting, what you are seeing as "null" are very likely not "null", but non-null strings consisting entirely of "whitespace" (most likely spaces and/or tabs). It is a very common (but very wrong) practice to enter a single space as a "placeholder" for `null`. (I have seen this especially in PS products... )

Comment: Of course, we don't know your data, but on the face of it I'd expect a column named PROJECT_ID to be NOT NULL, and probably some very tight controls on what is allowed to be put there in the first place - thus also eliminating just whitespace.  The fact that you are having this problem is highly suggestive of a severe shortcoming in either the data model or the application code.

Comment: @EdStevens - you are assuming that `project_id` is the primary key in this table. I doubt that's the case here. As for the "data model", I believe PeopleSoft itself is the culprit. (Note the leading `PS_` in the table name.) From what I have been told, the default is for all columns in PS tables to be `not null`, except for date columns. A single space is otherwise used as a substitute. That is an idiotic practice, agreed - but likely not one over which the OP has any say. And do note that PeopleSoft is (now) owned by Oracle!

Comment: @mathguy - You are correct.  I hadn't picked up on it being a PS table.  On the other hand, I didn't really assume PROJECT_ID was a PK.  Even if the table uses a surrogate key (which i did consider in my thinking), any column named SOMETHING_ID (noting the 'ID') is strongly indicative of being critical data for which NOT NULL would be called for.

Comment: What data type is the `project_id` column?

Comment: @EdStevens - "id" may also indicate a foreign key, which can very well be `null`. For example: "manager_id" pointing to "employee_id"; manager id may be null (for the company chairman or CEO).

Comment: @mathguy - well, I didn't say "definitive", just highly suggestive ..    ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You dont have nulls but blank spaces add below in your query

```
 SELECT project_id, monetary_amount, 
  journal_line_date 
  FROM PS_JRNL_LN 
    where ( project_id is not null or
   ( project_id is not 
     null   
    and  LTRIM( RTrim(project_id)) not 
       like '') 
     and 
     journal_line_date BETWEEN 
     to_date ('2020/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') 
                        AND TO_DATE 
   ('2020/03/04','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: `ltrim(rtrim(str))` is the same as `trim(str)`. But your query actually has an error: comparing to `null` with the `not like` operator is plain wrong.

Comment: You are still comparing with `not like ''` - that is incorrect. Should be `is not null`. (And it seems you didn't understand what I said about applying both `ltrim` and `rtrim`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can help you find out what is happening in the `project_id` column. (Most likely, a bunch of `' '` values, meaning non-empty string consisting of a single space.)

```
select project_id, dump(project_id)
from   ps_jrnl_ln
where  ltrim(project_id, chr(32) || chr(9)) is null
  and  project_id is not null
;
```

`DUMP` shows you exactly what is stored in your table. 32 is the ASCII code for a single space; 9 (or 09) is the code for horizontal tab. I expect you will get rows where the DUMP column shows a single character, with code 32. But - who knows; you may find other things as well.

That will help you understand what's in the column. (You may also check `describe ps_jrnl_ln` - you may find out that the column is declared `not null`!!!)

If you find a bunch of rows where the project id is a single space, of course, in your actual query you will have to change

```
where project_id is not null
```

to

```
where ltrim(project_id, chr(32) || chr(9)) is not null
```

Or, perhaps, if indeed a single space is used as placeholder for `null`:

```
where project_id != ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you must implement in your table design to prevent the problem at first place than struggling with the data:

1. Add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the column.
2. Add a `CHECK` constraint to prevent unwanted characters like whitespaces etc. and only allow the data you want to load.
3. If you don't want a check constraint, then handle it during loading the data using `TRIM`.
4. If necessary, make the PROJECT_ID column the primary key, that would implicitly not allow NULL values. Usually, the ID column in a table suggests it's a primary key but it could vary in your use case.

If you are not allowed to alter the design by doing none of the above, then at least you could handle the data insertion at application level where you might be taking it as input.

Answer (score 0):

Try using filter condition:

```
ltrim(rtrim(project_id)) <> ''
```

Comment: Why ltrim, rtrim both when you could simply use TRIM?

Comment: And `''` is a NULL, you can't compare it as `<> ''`. You need to use IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join that journal table to the source of truth for Project ID's. Assuming there are no "blank" ID's in that table, then you won't get "blanks" in your result.

e.g.

```
SELECT j.project_id, j.monetary_amount, j.journal_line_date 
FROM PS_JRNL_LN J

  INNER JOIN PROJECT_MASTER P ON j.project_id = p.id /* should remove "blanks" */

where j.journal_line_date >= to_date ('2020/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') 
and  j.journal_line_date < TO_DATE ('2020/03/05','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Note also, I never use `between` for date ranges, the above pattern using `>=` & `<` is more reliable (as it works regardless of the time precision of the data).